# Predicting continuous variables from text features

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, text-mining, naive-bayes

I want to predict a continuous variable from text features. Lets say I have some student essays and I want to predict their quality, as measured by a human grader, using text features (mostly words they use).

Linear regression is an obvious candidate, but if I have substantially more features than graded essays, this probably won't do well.

If I wanted to classify them into good/bad, I might try the Naive Bayes classifier. I don't, but maybe I can draw inspiration from that.

As I understand, Naive Bayes draws its power from assuming feature independence. Is there such a thing as Naive Multivariate Linear Regression, where you assume feature independence?

I think this is the same as using Univariate Linear Regression for each regression coefficient. I would expect that to run into problems quickly, though.

Is there something halfway between these two models? 
Putting a prior distribution on feature covariance that mostly expects conditional independence? Other models I should consider?

Bayesian models preferred.

Comment: I believe you are describing bag-of-words representation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) as far as the regression-based (non-bayesian) model goes. One can add bigrams and trigrams to the bag to capture higher order interactions.

Comment: This is no criticism of your efforts, John, but it is sad to realize that you might be successful, because--by not accounting at all for word sequence, sentence structure, or underlying ideas--achieving good predictability based merely on words used would indicate how little the human grading really has to do with quality of writing or thought.

Comment: You may want to look into John Myles White's [`TextRegression` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TextRegression/) for `R`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question has been asked on stackoverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087322/how-to-predict-a-continuous-value-time-from-text-documents

One answer here was to use k-nearest-neighbor regression to predict a continuous value from text documents, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15089788/179014.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Gradient Boosting with trees as described in chapter 10 "Boosting and Additive Trees" of [The elements of statistical learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/). These approach is suitable for bag-of-words-data, can catch interaction of word-features and can be used for both regression and classification.

Answer (score 1):

There is a type of Bayesian linear regression that handles the case of many features.  It is called latent factor regression and you can find a good description in the paper [Bayesian Factor Regression Models
in the "Large p, Small n" Paradigm](http://ftp.isds.duke.edu/WorkingPapers/02-12.html).  If the number of latent factors is large, then it is equivalent to linear regression.  Otherwise, it encourages the regression to follow the principal components of the features.